# Github: How to embed a gist into README.md?

Tags: github, markdown

Is it possible to embed gists into README.md file that resides in a GitHub repository?

Something like:

```
<code id="gist-3167145"></code>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Update : My answer works with github pages, built via jekyll. I use the script tags in markdown which is then processed by jekyll.

Since markdown supports html, one can simply use the **`<script>`** tag to embed gist.

Simply copy the embed url of the gist provided by [github](https://gist.github.com/)

[image]

..and paste it in you markdown file.

**Example :** Copy the below and paste in your markdown file.

`<script src="https://gist.github.com/nisrulz/11c0d63428b108f10c83.js"></script>`

..and this is what you will get

[image]

Comment: With GitHub [markup](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md) (#2): `The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as script tags...`

Comment: @philipvr agree with that doc, but this still works and solves the OP's question.

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem? If you try to embed a gist this way for a GitHub repo's readme.md file, the embeded gist will not be shown.

Comment: @philipvr i get what you were pointing out. I updated my answer to reflect the environment in which this works for me.

Comment: This URL for this technique also accepts an optional argument for file name, `?file=file_name_here`.  E.g., `<script src="https://gist.github.com/nisrulz/11c0d63428b108f10c83.js?file=test.sh"></script>

Answer (score 31):

No, sorry, that is not possible.  You will have to either have a link to it in your README.md or copy its contents.

[Github Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) will show you what you can put in your README.md file.

Comment: Thanks philip, I was hoping that somehow I had missed it when reading the documentation or the documentation itself could be outdated. :-D

That would be a cool feature though.

Comment: [There is a closed issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/199) requesting this feature. Unfortunately it looks like it won't be available anytime soon.

Answer (score 5):

This is do-able in 2017 when using *GitHub Pages* and a Jekyll theme:

See https://gist.github.com/benbalter/5555251 from [@benbalter](https://gist.github.com/benbalter)

Simple as: `{% gist 123456789 %}`

Comment: This markup also accepts an optional file name argument, `{% gist 5555251 gist.md %}.  If the gist contains that file name, then only that file name will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you are using a markdown preprocessor such as [Gitdown](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown):

```js
/**
 * Resolve Gist (https://gist.github.com/)
 *
 * @param {Object} config
 * @param {String} config.id Gist ID.
 * @param {String} config.fileName Gist file name. Default to gistfile1.txt.
 */
gitdown.registerHelper('gist', {
    compile: function (config) {
        config = config || {};
        config.fileName = config.fileName || 'gistfile1.txt';

        if (!config.id) {
            throw new Error('Gist ID must be provided.');
        }

        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            var https = require('https');

            https.get({
                host: 'api.github.com',
                path: '/gists/' + config.id,
                headers: {
                    // User agent is required to communicate with Github API.
                    'user-agent': 'Gitdown – gist'
                }
            }, function(res) {
                var body = '';

                res.setEncoding('utf8');

                res.on('data', function (d) {
                    body += d;
                });

                res.on('end', function () {
                    var gist = JSON.parse(body);

                    if (!gist.files) {
                        throw new Error('Gist ("' + config.id + '") not found.');
                    }

                    if (!gist.files[config.fileName]) {
                        throw new Error('File ("' + config.fileName + '") is not part of the gist ("' + config.id + '").');
                    }

                    resolve(gist.files['gistfile1.txt'].content);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Then in your markdown your would reference the Gist using a JSON hook, e.g.

```
{"gitdown": "gist", "id": "d3e4212c799252bac5fa"}
```

This feature should become part of the Gitdown in a near future (there is an open issue, https://github.com/gajus/gitdown/issues/7).

Answer (score 2):

Some people will end up here due to the fact that they want to use auto-generated gists to make their profile on github more interesting with activity box, productive box, etc. ([list of this stuff](https://github.com/matchai/awesome-pinned-gists)).
However, you should note that these auto-generated gists should not be added to your profile dedicated README file but should be pinned using the "**Customize your pins**" option on your profile page.