# How to display line numbers using GitHub Flavored Markdown "code"?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I know I can use "code" in GitHub Flavored Markdown to highlight a code snippet. But I am not able to display line numbers for a snippet. Is there a way to do so?

````
```javascript
var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
alert(s);
```
````

I want a line number to be put at the beginning of each line, like this:

```
1    var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
2    alert(s);
```

Comment: I know it is not an answer to your question but you can try to using embedded Gist in your Readme/wiki pages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622509/github-how-to-embed-a-gist-into-readme-md

Comment: Related question on Meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7119/why-are-there-no-line-numbers-in-the-code-listings

Comment: This could be useful https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet

Comment: Line number are not in standard markdown standard, but some libraries might implement extended functionality such as the one you want. Just look around for a library that offers it.

Comment: Related to the comments by @GabrielOshiro - [Creating a permanent link to a code snippet](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet).

Answer (score 44):

As you may noticed in [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code-and-syntax-highlighting), GitHub does not show line numbers in code blocks.

Comment: sad, but thank you for saving my time

Answer (score 6):

As a hack, you could save a pic of your code at https://carbon.now.sh and post it; they support line numbers as an option.

Comment: I cry whenever I can't copy and paste code from code blocks :(

Comment: As a hack, you could include the source-code in another way into your markdown. of course... But does this answer the question? The question was how to do this using plain "GitHub Flavored Markdown code" and not using anything else.

Answer (score 6):

You can get something similar that you need using `awk '{printf("% 4d  %s\n", NR, $0)}' StartDsl.scala` where StartDsl.scala is your source code file. Paste the result between

````
```scala
<your code here>
```
````

Answer (score 6):

Although it is not available in GitHub as the question asks, I have discovered today if you add an `=` sign after the opening line, on some Markdown editors, it gives the desired result.

eg:

````
```javascript=
var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
alert(s);
```
````

This works on Markdown editors such as [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/new)

See [your example](https://hackmd.io/EQrGZM7-Qz6xIFZiTZav8A?both) on HackMD

Answer (score 5):

So, you will need to help yourself by adding css to your html page. As a code goes into `<pre> </pre>` block in markdown.

You could apply your logic to this block to put line number against each line.

See https://codepen.io/heiswayi/pen/jyKYyg for reference.

Answer (score 5):

I use RStudio with  RMarkdown to render my Markdown (`.md`) files. It works great. Using the RMarkdown, the specification is made this way:

````html
```{.javascript .numberLines .lineAnchors}
var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
alert(s);
```
````

Yes, there are many markdown editors available and I'm not sure that this will work with all the editors, but RStudio/RMarkdown is a really great tool, which I use since a long time ago (IMHO).

Answer (score -3):

Just add an = after the language you choose !

````
```java=
java code exemple:
int i = 5
```java=
````

Comment: This may work for other Markdown renderers but not in Github.

Answer (score -7):

Now here is the solution for adding line numbers in Markdown.

https://shd101wyy.github.io/markdown-preview-enhanced/#/markdown-basics?id=line-numbers

> You can enable line number for a code block by adding **line-numbers**
>   class.

Comment: it is working for my text-editor with markdown plugin, but I couldn't see any line numbers in github code-blocks (in my comments for code at least)

Comment: Dude, this is MPE and not part of GitHub... "Markdown Preview Enhanced is a SUPER POWERFUL markdown extension for Atom and Visual Studio Code. The goal of this project is to bring you a wonderful markdown writing experience."