# show license.md in github online directory like README.md

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I've made a license for a program where I am working on.

My question is: is it possible to show a file (in my situation: `license.md`) as a `readme.md` in a github directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in GitHub makrdown itself (see [issues 172](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/172#issuecomment-33241601))

> For now, we're not going to allow any includes in any of our markup formats.
>   There's just too much overhead to making sure that there are no security vulnerabilities in each of the markup formats we support.

It is possible with [github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622509/github-how-to-embed-a-gist-into-readme-md/32030995#32030995) built with Jekyll, or with [some kind of preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files) for markdown pages in general.

But there is no include with GitHub repo markdown files themselves.

In your case, it is best to generate your `README.md` by making sure its content include the latest revision of your `LICENSE.md` ([for instance, through a pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16832764/6309)).