# How to quote code in a Mardkown GitHub Gist

Tags: github, gist

In a markdown file in a Gist, how do you quote some lines of code that are in a GitHub project?

If I was writing a Gist to try and explain how something works, I might have a block of text, then quote some code. I don't want to cut and paste the code in, I just want to quote some lines of code in a GitHub project. I am sure I have seen this done, but can't find an explanation of how to do it.

For example:

This algorithm makes use of Dijkstra's topological sort algorithm:

```
100: Result myFancyPantsAlgorithm(Blah blah) {
101:    youGetTheIdea();
102: }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to embed GitHub code snippets from Repositories.

What you might have seen is having a gist embedded in a "normal" website which is possible because GitHub provides a script to [embed gists](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#embedding-gists).

The script tag is (un)fortunately [not whitelisted](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L44-L49) to be used in GitHub Flavored Markdown, so it is not possible to embed a gist in markdown.

A way to get around this would be to set a gh-page up, where you are able to embed a Gist as this [SO-question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622509/github-how-to-embed-a-gist-into-readme-md). But then you're still not referencing to any live codebase.

So the answer to your question is: this is not possible, wether by embedding code from a repository nor by taking a detour via using gists.

Comment: I don't want to embed a Gist into something else. I want to embed some code in a Gist.

Comment: I understood what you said - i (hopefully) clarified my answer.