# How to embed a gist in another gist

Tags: shell, github, markdown, gist, github-flavored-markdown

As the title says how can you embed one gist (a shell script) into another gist (markdown file)?

- js is disabled so not scripts embeding
- github's {% gist *id* %} does not work.

Is there a way?
Thanks

Comment: Markdown has no concept of including one file in another. Some third party addons have provided such a feature, but it is non-standard and not likely to be supported across implementations. I can't say definitively (so this is not an answer), but I suspect this is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github: How to embed a gist into README.md?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622509/github-how-to-embed-a-gist-into-readme-md)

Comment: Yeah, idk if gist had any extra features but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

An embedded gist is an `<iframe>` included via an inline `<script>` tag, for example, [from the GitHub Blog announcing embedded gists](https://github.com/blog/122-embedded-gists):

[image: embedded gist #DOM]

The best you can hope with gist is to make a gist with multiple files (which you [can do easily](https://gist.github.com/michaelsanford/c07231c457867c2c2acad062769c6b62)) and then just link or textually reference the other.

Or, better, to choose another publishing platform, like GitHub pages (if you're using gists already). If you're at the point that you're embedding code snippits into others, you *probably* want something that's a bit more flexible and customizable.

Comment: Yeah, that really what I got from reading other questions but thanks for clarifying.

Comment: well it does not work on md/gists but i think i up voted it, sry. Me been under 15 rep does not show it publically i think

Comment: @Max The up arrow above the number on the left. Also, the check mark will be outlined below the down arrow, also left. I mention it partly because you'll get +2 for accepting an answer. :)