# Display GitHub Gist while rendering Markdown client-side

Tags: markdown, client-side, gist, html-rendering, javascript-marked

How can one display the contents of a GitHub Gist while [parsing a markdown file client-side using Marked.js](https://marked.js.org/using_pro#extensions) or with [any other client Markdown library](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-client-markdown-rendering-libraries)? The code below renders the Markdown file **except the Gist**.

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/testfolder/StachExgMdScript.md")
    .then(response => response.blob())  // Unwrap to a blob...
    .then(blob => blob.text())          // ...then to raw text...
    .then(markdown => {        // .pass raw text into marked.parse
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=marked.parse(markdown)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

However, the Gist renders OK in Visual Studio Code after disabling `Markdown content preview settings` :  `Disable preview security warning in this workspace`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can give you a heads up : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622509/github-how-to-embed-a-gist-into-readme-md

Comment: @SARANSURYA, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32030995/2748772) provides a solution for [Jekyll](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#viewing-jekyll-build-error-messages-with-github-actions) that renders the pages to HTML in the repository. I'm trying to fetch and render the Markdown file client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs additional JavaScript to run the script tag while rendering Markdown client side.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/testfolder/StachExgMdScript.md")
        .then((response) => response.text()) // Unwrap to a blob...
        .then((markdown) => {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = marked.parse(markdown);
            var scriptTags = document.querySelectorAll("#content script");
            function handleDocumentWrite(content) {
                var contentPlaceholder = document.getElementById("content");
                contentPlaceholder.innerHTML += content}
            window.document.write = handleDocumentWrite;
            scriptTags.forEach(function(scriptTag) {
                if (scriptTag.src) {
                    var externalScript = document.createElement("script");
                    externalScript.src = scriptTag.src;
                    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(externalScript);
                } else {eval(scriptTag.innerText); }
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring because Marked.js is not executing the script in the parsed markdown file. I'm not sure which libraries would allow you to do this but according to this you might be able to do this in Docsify-JS
https://gist.github.com/MichaelCurrin/c2bece08f27c4277001f123898d16a7c

You need to enable this executescript:true in order to run the inline scripts
https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=executescript

Comment: I had tried that too. The [Docsify team confirmed on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/713647066802421792/1087565808856735818/1087761151510712456) that [they didn't support it](https://gist.github.com/MichaelCurrin/c2bece08f27c4277001f123898d16a7c#gist-embedded-with-a-script-tag).