# Display contents of a file with code using markdown and revealjs

Tags: markdown, reveal.js

I am writing a presentation in a markdown file referenced by Reveal.JS.
I would like to import external file's source code in a markdown code block without having to do copy & paste. Ideally I would like to put a relative path to the file like I can do with an image.

Is it supported? I couldn't find it mentioned in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Markdown does not support including content from external files, and I'm not aware of any Markdown extensions that add this feature.

You may be able to hack together a solution by concatenating files together, e.g.

**`01-intro1.md`:**

````
# My title

Some content, check out this example:

```
````

**`02-example1.js`:**

```
var foo = 'FOO';
```

**`03-intro2.md`:**

````
```

More content.
````

Generate your presentation file with `cat 01-intro1.md 02-example1.js 03-intro2.md > presentation.md`.

For more details, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files).

Comment: I will probably end up using Grunt to concatenate the files.

Comment: Hello @MarcoBettiolo can you answer your own question with steps for concatenating files using Grunt ?

Answer (score 2):

This is way old, but I found it while looking for a way to do the same thing...

There are some "helper packages" for Reveal.js that support including an external file. [present](https://github.com/zharley/present) has support for doing it in Markdown, and [reveal-ck](http://jedcn.github.io/reveal-ck) supports it in a number of other formats (but, as far as I can tell, not Markdown).

The author of [present](https://github.com/zharley/present) wrote up his approach in this post: [Presentation tools for programmers: Reveal.js](http://zenonharley.com/html5/css3/2015/12/07/presentation-tools-for-programmers-reveal-js.html).