# How to include an external code file in rmakdown to output in pdf with sintax highlight

Tags: r, latex, pdf-generation, r-markdown, listings

My question is inspired from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857212/incorporate-code-listings-from-an-external-file-in-knitr-markdown). However, the difference is that my output is PDF.

I have a `C++` code saved in an external file. I want to print it into a r markdown PDF with syntax highlight.

My `example.cpp` code, which is in fact a `TMB` code:

```
// Fitting Bivariate Gaussian distribution.
#include <TMB.hpp>
template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
  using namespace density;
  DATA_MATRIX(Y);
  PARAMETER_VECTOR(rho);
  PARAMETER_VECTOR(sigma);
  vector<Type> rho_temp(1);
  rho_temp = rho;
  vector<Type> sigma_temp(2);
  sigma_temp = sigma;
  Type res;
  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    res += VECSCALE(UNSTRUCTURED_CORR(rho_temp), sigma_temp)(Y.row(i));
  return res;
}
```

Minimal code:

````
---
title: "Code to PDF"
output: beamer_presentation
safe-columns: true # enables special latex macros for columns
header-includes:
- \usepackage{listings}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
setwd("/home/guilherme/Google Drive/Mestrado/dissertacao/TMB/Presentation")
```

## Slide1

\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{example.cpp}
````

result in the slide:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this highlighting?

Comment: You could probably simplify your command with `\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{example.cpp}`.  Maybe with some \`\`\`{latex}... around it. Can you make a [mre] to test?

Comment: I just did it with your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a lot of engines in Rmarkdown. You can find them [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html).

In general case:

My C++ archive, which I named as 'mycpp.cpp':

```cpp
# include <iostream>

class Passaro                       // classe base
{
public:
   virtual void MostraNome()
   {
      std::cout << "um passaro";
   }
   virtual ~Passaro() {}
};

class Cisne: public Passaro         // Cisne é um pássaro
{
public:
   void MostraNome()
   {
      std::cout << "um cisne";        // sobrecarrega a função virtual
   }
};

int main()
{
   Passaro* passaro = new Cisne;

   passaro->MostraNome();            // produz na saída "um cisne", e não "um pássaro"

   delete passaro;
}
```

My Rmd archive:

````r
---
title: "Code to PDF"
output:
  pdf_document
---

# Cats are nicer than dogs

```{Rcpp, code=readLines('mycpp.cpp')}
```
````

Output:

[image]

Especific to your case, try this:

````r
---
title: "Code to PDF"
output: beamer_presentation
safe-columns: true # enables special latex macros for columns
header-includes:
- \usepackage{listings}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
setwd("/home/guilherme/Google Drive/Mestrado/dissertacao/TMB/Presentation")
```

## Slide1

```{Rcpp, eval = FALSE, echo = TRUE, code=readLines('example.cpp')}
```
````