# include markdown inside markdown

Tags: html, include, markdown

Is there a way to use include keyword to include an .md file inside another .md file?

I have an HTML block inside my .md file, and inside that block I want to call a different .md file like this:

```
<div class="example" id="1">
#include "path/to/file/to/be/included/file.md"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not with standard Markdown. Which Markdown library are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markdown and including multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files)