# Multiple markdown files to a single HTML

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have to convert multiple .md files into a single HTML file.

Is it possible? Pandoc can convert .md to HTMLbut not sure if it can do it for multiple files.

Or would I need to write a program to manipulate the tool?

Comment: ... just concatenate them together? Would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pandoc *.md -o result.html
```

Try this

Comment: pandoc: *.md: openBinaryFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files

Comment: Thanks for the link.This is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the files in lexicographical order of their names by using the following command:

```
pandoc *.md > all.html
```

For example, if in your folder, you have files like this:

```
k.md, w.md, t.md, a.md
```

they will be concatenated in following order:

```
a.md
k.md
t.md
w.md
```

the final output file will be

```
all.html
```