# Include markdown files in another Readme.md in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

In Azure Devops, there is the possibility to view Readme.md files, but I would like to include/merge some text from another .md-file into that document. Or perhaps combine them in a wiki.

I am not able to find documentation on doing these kind of operations.

I have heard of tools like Pandoc and Sphinx, but I am not sure if Azure Devops supports that on their web app.

Comment: I think that the top answer to this question also answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown syntax supports include other md files `[link text](file-name.md)`, however these files can only be rendered as links.
It seems azure devops does not support pandoc or sphinx, for I could not find any related extensions on azure devops marketplace.
There is a suggestion that you can build your README.md file using pandoc to include/merge other md files, or other methods mentioned in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files) @eskwayrd commented, before you commit to your repo.